# php unlink permission denied with while or if

Tags: php, permissions

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I am trying to delete images in a specific folder after a condition exists. The condition is to limit more than eight images or photos. **It works when I delete one image, but as soon as I add the while or if** condition, it gives access denied error.

Below is my code that checks the db for the condition and then supposedly deletes the image from the folder:

```
mysql_select_db($database_rentaguide, $rentaguide);
$query_overflow_images = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbl_rentalimages WHERE sessionid = %s AND image_id > '$lastimageid'",
    GetSQLValueString($colname_overflow_images, "text"));
$overflow_images = mysql_query($query_overflow_images, $rentaguide) or die(mysql_error());
$row_overflow_images = mysql_fetch_assoc($overflow_images);
$totalRows_overflow_images = mysql_num_rows($overflow_images);

while ($row_overflow_images = mysql_fetch_assoc($overflow_images)); {
    $overflowpath = $row_overflow_images['image_url'];
    chmod("../".$overflowpath, 0777);
    unlink("../".$overflowpath);
}
```

The actual path of the image is --> `rentalimages/LqXtyVtzKm/architecture-1836070__340.jpg`

The $lastimageid variable comes from the db connection that gets the id of the eighth or last record where and if there are more than eight images.

Please help me. Please

Oh yes, I am running xampp on Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Why the call to `chmod()`? Either you do have write permission to the file or you do not, the chmod command cannot somehow help you to gain such permission. And certainly setting an image file executable does not make any sense at all.

Comment: Please dump the list of files `$overflowpath` inside the while loop into some log file and check the result. Maybe there is some unexpected value inside the database?

Comment: A general note: you are using the outdated, long deprecated `mysql_...()` functions. That extension has even be removed completely for php-7 for security reasons. You should immediately port your code to the more secure `mysqli` extension.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code, right before the body of the `while` block (edit - forgot to mention the typo is the semicolon):

```
/* Empty loop, followed by a code block */
while ($row_overflow_images = mysql_fetch_assoc($overflow_images));
{
    /* $row_overflow_images is no longer an array */
    $overflowpath = $row_overflow_images['image_url'];
    chmod("../".$overflowpath, 0777);
    /* This line tries to delete the parent folder */
    unlink("../".$overflowpath);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked at the end....

```
mysql_select_db($database_rentaguide, $rentaguide);
$query_overflow_images = sprintf("SELECT * FROM tbl_rentalimages WHERE 
sessionid = %s AND image_id > '$lastimageid'", 
GetSQLValueString($colname_overflow_images, "text"));
$overflow_images = mysql_query($query_overflow_images, $rentaguide) or 
die(mysql_error());
$row_overflow_images = mysql_fetch_assoc($overflow_images);
$totalRows_overflow_images = mysql_num_rows($overflow_images);
do {
    $filepath = $row_overflow_images['image_url'];
    $imageid = $row_overflow_images['image_id'];

  $deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM tbl_rentalimages WHERE image_id = %s",
                       GetSQLValueString($imageid, "int"));

  mysql_select_db($database_rentaguide, $rentaguide);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $rentaguide) or die(mysql_error());
  unlink("../".$filepath);

}
while ($row_overflow_images = mysql_fetch_assoc($overflow_images));

}
```

P.S. I know I should port to the mysqli extension, but I am only practicing and trying to learn more. Thanks stachoverflow. You guys are awesome!